# How do I manually start/stop the motion service from a program?

Tags: motion, services

I have successfully set up motion to run at boot up on a Raspberry Pi running buster Debian Linux.

Now I want to start and stop the service from within my Python program.  I started by changing the `/etc/default/motion` file from `start_motion_daemon=yes` to `start_motion_daemon=no` and then rebooting, but the motion service was still automatically starting on boot.  Then I ran

```
sudo systemctl disable motion
```

and rebooted.  That worked.  After this, I could successfully issue the command

```
sudo service motion start
```

from within my Python program via a subprocess.run() call and the service would start successfully.  However, no motion capture occurred after this.  Issuing the command

```
sudo service motion status
```

revealed a message saying `No /usr/bin/motion`.

Does anyone know how to properly do this?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to abandon running motion as a service and use subprocess.Popen() from within my program to start and stop the motion application.